# drawing a sine function in a r plot

Tags: r

I would like to draw a simple `sin` and such a function

[image]

in a R plot.

I am using this code:

```
plot(sin, 0,  2*pi)
curve((4sin+(1/3)sin(3x))/pi, xlim = c(0, 2*pi), n = 1001, col = "blue", add = TRUE)
```

but I get this error:

```
Error: unexpected symbol in "curve((4sin"
```

What should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Try `4*sin(x)` and the same for the rest.

Comment: Or `4*sin(x)+(1/3)*sin(3*x)`

Comment: It is actually `4*(sin(x)+(1/3)*sin(3*x))/pi`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't like the * symbol?

```
plot(sin, 0,  2*pi)
curve(4*(sin(x)+(1/3)*sin(3*x))/pi, xlim = c(0, 2*pi), n = 1001, col = "blue", add = TRUE)
```